# If a particle has multiple quantum states (for position) in superposition, can it be at multiple places?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, superposition

When a particle like an electron is at x position, it is at a quantum state for that position. If it has more of these states, can it be at more positions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do multiple electrons exist during superposition?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51891/)

Answer (score 2):

Until we measure it, and therefore fix it's position (**for the time of measurement only**), the idea of it having "a position or positions" is not really meaningful in quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is that when you do a measurement to find a particles position you will always measure it to be at one position $x$ with a measurement uncertainty of $\Delta x$.

Every wave function $\Psi(x)$ will already give you a multitude of possible valid $x$ positions with different probabilities to occur. (note: $\delta(x)$ is not a valid wave function as it is not square-integrable)So you do dot need the superposition for the basis of your question. 
When you do your measurement to determine the current position of the particle, the previous state $\lvert \Psi \rangle$ breaks down to (i.e. will be projected to) a state in a basis which is given by your measurement $\lvert\Phi\rangle= \sum_{i} \phi_i \lvert\Phi\rangle $.

The wiki page about the [Measurement in quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_in_quantum_mechanics) is a good follow up to read.

Comment: Nitpick: The "almost" is unnecessary, *every* wavefunction has uncertainty in position. The only imaginable "function" that does not - $\delta(x)$ - is neither square-integrable nor a function to begin with, so it is not an allowed state.

Comment: In fact I was was using almost because of $\delta(x)$. Thank you for refreshing my memory that it is not square-integrable @ACuriousMind.

Answer (score 2):

A particle can be in [quantum superposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_superposition), which can place it in multiple [quantum states](https://www.quora.com/In-laymans-term-what-is-a-quantum-state) simultaneously.  However, if the particle is "observed", that is if information is extracted from it, the quantum states will [decohere](https://www.physics.drexel.edu/~tim/open/main/node2.html), and the particle then will occupy only the state in which it is "observed".

Researchers at the [University of Bonn designed a clever experiment](https://www.uni-bonn.de/Press-releases/atoms-can-be-in-two-places-at-the-same-time) which may have succeeded in pulling a single Caesium atom to two places at once.  The had to use indirect measurements to avoid quantum decoherence.

Answer (score 0):

It is only at one place at any given time which we find only by detection. It certainly is not at more than one positions at a time because that has never been detected experimentally.

Comment: No, the issue is not "smallness" at all. It's that it is *inherently meaningless* to talk of "the position" of a quantum object prior to position measurement unless in terms of expectation values and standard deviations.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: changed.

Comment: "certainly not" and "because" does not compute.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: If "experimentally" does not compute, then nothing computes.